# Date Picker empty when saved

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have customized my SharePoint list form using Power Apps.

I created a date picker inside of the Power Apps not on the SharePoint or data source itself. The problem is when saved, the value selected on date picker is showing blank. I want the value selected to reflect even after saving the item.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you create a date column in your SharePoint list?

Comment: No but the target is that date picker should not be created on SharePoint. With that, is it still possible for date picker to reflect the date when saved?